# Javascript Menu - Scrolling/Content Jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a nice little javascript menu, which purposely doesn't use data tags as I was having issued with html purifier conflicts (another, long story).

Anyway, after alot of tinkering, the functionality and styling works exactly as I wanted, but with one exception - when I click on each menu item, it opens the content at different points on the screen, seemingly depending on the amount of content.  I want it to always open at the top, so that the menu is always visible, along with the top of the content, and you can then scroll down as you wish.

I've been trying to resolve this for a while, so would appreciate any assistance, or amending of the attached fiddle.

Thanks in advance

Paul

https://jsfiddle.net/awcguxs5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var lastItem = null;
$('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function () {
    newItem = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);
    if (newItem != lastItem) {
            $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').hide(600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('#' + newItem).show(600);
        lastItem = newItem;
    }
}).find('a:first').click();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the references are still going to the corresponding ID locations. I've added one line of jquery that will scroll the page back to the top after the click. here is the line added:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1);
```

Here is your jsfiddle with this line:

https://jsfiddle.net/awcguxs5/2/

Let me know if this is what you were looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens precisely because you did not want to use "data tags".

Add this to `onclick` block:

```
$('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    .... //rest of your code.
```

`e.preventDefault()` will stop the default action of `a-href`, which in your case uses `#div1` anchors to jump to that `div`.

Your updated fiddle here: **https://jsfiddle.net/awcguxs5/3/**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var lastItem = null;
$('#listingmenu').on('click', 'a', function () {
    newItem = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);
    if (newItem != lastItem) {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox').hide( 600);
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        setTimeout( function(){$('#' + newItem).show(600)} , 600 );
        lastItem = newItem;
    }
}).find('a:first').click();
```

});

The settimeout fixes the issue and gives -i think- a nicer effect than firing the hide and the show simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that works great.  I was looking to have two of these menus on my page, but when I do so, it doesn't open the first menu item on the second menu (if that makes sense).  Instead, it opens the first item in menu one, but leaves everything closed in menu 2? I have made sure each menu item has a different div number, and that the classes are all unique to avoid conflict, but it doesn't seem to help.  It just stacks the menus, and opens the first item in just one menu?

Comment: If you did copy/pasted all my code, that behaviour should come because I removed the id of the item when hiding, so my code  was hiding all the boxes: $('.pbox').hide( 600);